# Python3 if Statement in a Loop

Tags: python, loops, if-statement

I am getting "R, B, C, and P" for my outputs when it should be "Residential, Business, City, and Parish"

I am also getting 0.00 for my total, I need the total if its a business, city, or parish (They are all different)...it is not computing.

I am getting my inputs from a .data file and they are correct

```
print("=========================================================")
print(format("Name", '<12s'),format("Type", '<15s'),format("Location", '<10s'),format("KwH", '>6s'),format("Total", '>10s'))
print("=========================================================")
total = 0
for i in range(10):
    custName = input()
    custType = input()
    custLoc = input()
    custKwh = eval(input())
    if (custType == "R"):
        custType = "Residential"
    if (custType == "B"):
        custType = "Business"
        total = (custKwh * 0.05710) + 10
    if (custLoc == "C"):
        custLoc = "City"
        total = (custKwh * 0.0401) + 6
    if (custLoc == "P"):
        custLoc = "Parish"
        total = (custKwh * 0.04411) + 6.60
    print(format(custName, '<12s'),format(custType, '<15s'),format(custLoc, '<10s'),format(custKwh, '>6d'),format(total, '>10.2f'))
```

inputs are:

```
Smith R P 4500 Taylor R C 6000 Williams B C 10500 Johnson R C 7500 Davis R P 3000 Woods B P 25300 Morgan R C 5800 Landry R C 3900 Young B P 18500 Wilson R P 7000
```

Comment: First, I don't see how you are getting any outputs since you are not outputting anything.  Second, perhaps you should give an example of your inputs after you update your code showing how you output.

Comment: code updated, this is my whole code..

Comment: looks like your input needs you to press enter after every value, it's all getting put in the custName variable. You could fix it by having one input go into all the diff variables with .split(' ')

Comment: I have it entered after every value in the data file...I didn't want to take up a lot of space so I just entered them that way on here

Comment: the other thing you need to do is set `custLoc` instead of `custType` in your if statements for `custLoc`

Comment: good catch, I changed it but it still didn't change anything

Answer (score 1):

I would rewrite it as this:

```
print("=========================================================")
print(
    format("Name", '<12s'),
    format("Type", '<15s'),
    format("Location", '<10s'),
    format("KwH", '>6s'),
    format("Total", '>10s')
)
print("=========================================================")
total = 0
for i in range(10):
    custName, custType, custLoc, custKwh = input().split(' ')
    custKwh = int(custKwh)
    if (custType == "R"):
        custType = "Residential"
    if (custType == "B"):
        custType = "Business"
        total = (custKwh * 0.05710) + 10
    if (custLoc == "C"):
        custLoc = "City"
        total = (custKwh * 0.0401) + 6
    if (custLoc == "P"):
        custLoc = "Parish"
        total = (custKwh * 0.04411) + 6.60
    print(
        format(custName, '<12s'),
        format(custType, '<15s'),
        format(custLoc, '<10s'),
        format(custKwh, '>6d'),
        format(total, '>10.2f')
    )
```

The key error here is that you're setting custType again when checking custLoc (copy paste error?)

Comment: this is still not solving my problem, still getting R,B,C, and P.....and total values are still 0.00. Should I set total = to something else? Why is it not calculating

Comment: @user2865217 I am not chatting you. Just post your command or learn python on your own -- sorry to be harsh but we do this for free.

Comment: How are you running the script though? What's the exact command you're using to launch this. How are you getting the data?

Comment: python pa3.py < pa3.data - all inputs are saved in pa3.data, after each input is a enter

Comment: what's different between what you're seeing and what I'm seeing?
https://gist.github.com/ranman/6913539

Comment: that worked for me now, thanks! just curious..why isn't mine working? its almost the same thing?